# Updating UDT Set with CQLEngine

Tags: python, cassandra, cqlengine

I'm new to Cassandra and I'm trying to use CQLEngine ORM to update set column which holds UDT but I can't and documentation doesn't say anything about custom types.

My code is;

```
class MyType(UserType):

    val = columns.Text()
    point = columns.Integer()
    key = columns.Text()

    def __init__(self, val, point, key, **values):
        super().__init__(**values)
        self.val = val
        self.point = point
        self.key = key


class MyModel(Model):

    myid = columns.UUID(primary_key=True)
    set_clm = columns.Set(columns.Integer)
    mytype = columns.Set(UserDefinedType(MyType))

    def __init__(self, set_clm, mytype, **values):
        super().__init__(**values)
        self.myid = uuid4()
        self.set_clm = set_clm
        self.mytype = mytype



s = MyModel.objects(myid="2b3adb7d-9e68-49fc-9aa0-26dbec607f9d").update(
    mytype__add=set(MyType(val="1", point=2, key="3"))
)
```

MyModel initially holds NULL in set but when I try to update it, I get the following error:

`cassandra.InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Invalid set literal for mytype: value 'point' is not of type frozen<mytype>"`

`'point' is not of type frozen<mytype>` -> This part randomly changes  whenever I rerun the code (next time I'd run, I'd get the same error for 'val' column etc).

Can anyone help me how I can add a UDT set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. I've solved it. I'm writing it down for people who'd find it on Google.

This is the correct way of adding to a set: `mytype__add={MyType(val="1", point=2, key="3")}`

and also implement the `__hash__` function for MyType such as:

```
def __hash__():
    return hash(self.__repr__())
```

but with a smarter `__hash__` function. It's just an example. Hope it helps to someone else.